# How to get information from events per week to events per day?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was given the following homework question:

If a company's computer has around 28.14 errors per week. What is the probability of less than 3 errors at one day ?

Can someone give me a little start up aid to solve the question? (**no demand here, for solving my homework!**).

What I got so far:

I shall estimate $p(X<3)$,
therefore I could simply add the probabilities for $p(X=0)+p(X=1)+p(X=2)$.

But this is where I am struggling: How to get a useful information for any of those probabilities out of 28.14 per week?

$28.14/7 = 4.02$ So on average there is 4.02 errors per day. But how to know how likely it is that there's less or more than average on a day ?

Once again I am not asking for a solution but for a little help getting started.

Comment: To start you have to model the problem.  Different models will produce different answers.  I'd say the most natural thing would be to assume a Poisson process, but other choices are also possible.

Comment: Do I not need further infomartion like standard derivation then ?

Comment: A Poisson process is determined by its mean.  Similarly, you could try to come up with a binomial process that had the right mean.  I think Poisson is a lot simpler (and the answers should be extremely close).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the poisson distribution, you have a $Po(4)$ per day (approximating $4.02 \approx 4$)

So the requested probability is

$\mathbb{P}[X<3]=e^{-4}[1+4+\frac{4^2}{2!}]\approx 24\%$

it is understood that it is not forbidden to use exactly 4.02 a a mean errors per day....the calculation process is the same